# Unable to display NPOT texture with OpenGL

Tags: opengl, nvidia

I writing a C++ simple application, to figure out why i can't display any NPOT texture using "GL_Texture_2D" as the texture_target. At some point, I'll need to generate some Mipmaps, so 
using rectangle texture isn't an option.

I'm running Win7 Pro (x64), Intel i7-2600K CPU, 8GB ram, NVIDIA Quadro 600. My quadro's driver is 296.35, which support OpenGL 4.2.

1 Working version
When using the "default" texture, it runs smoothly and display any NPOT texture.

```
glBindTexture( target = GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture = 0 )
```

2 Broken version
Since, I'll need more that 1 texture, I need to get their "name".
As soon has we're trying to bind a named texture, calling glGenTexture and using that that texture into the glBindTexture, all I get is a white rectangle.

```
glGenTextures(n = 1, textures = &2)
glBindTexture(target = GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture = 2)
```

I'm sure that my hardware supports NPOT texture, I've checked openGL extensions and "GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two" is listed. Also, I'm using and instead of the typical windows version of .

I've also asked this question on the nvidia forums and [in this post](http://forums.developer.nvidia.com/devforum/discussion/9601/unable-to-display-npot-texture-with-opengl) you'll find both log files

Comment: Rectangle textures has nothing to do with NPOT textures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` defaults to `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR`.](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes#Creating_a_Texture)

Upload mipmaps or switch to `GL_NEAREST/GL_LINEAR`.